# Add filter to listview with two textview

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview

I have a custom `ListView` with two `TexView`, I fill it with a SimpleAdapter with this code below

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            R.layout.activity_lista_vehiculo,
            new String[] { "value1","value2" },
            new int[] {R.id.line_a, R.id.line_b});      
    setListAdapter( adapter );
```

How can i put a filter to it from an `EditText` or `SearchView`?

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleAdapter` has a build-in `SimpleFilter` which filters the content of your `ListView adapter` with a prefix. If this is what you want, you can use the following code to do the filter work:

```
            yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // When user changed the Text
                    yourSimpleAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs); 

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: I did it like it, i put the code to OnCreated Method and i have this error : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Proyect1/com.example.Proyect1.ListViewStudient}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: it's the same code that you put above. where you put "yourSimpleAdapter" i put my adapter, where you put 'yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() " i put txtsearch........,

Comment: Maybe txtsearch is null, please post your error stack that can be found in the logcat.